Optimize tikz Background Drawings
I have a problem with tikz drawings in my latex file.
What I'm doing:

I generate a latex file automatically based on some input data.
The generated file is quite huge (PDF has about 150 pages)
In this latex file I have many tables where I print a background tree to improve readability. See below.

This is just a small example, the tables in my generated document are larger, sometimes over several pages and have a more hierarchy levels concerning the tree.
\documentclass[8pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\PageOfTikzmark[1]{%
\csname save@pg@\csname save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}\endcsname\endcsname}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\connecttreenodes}[3][]{\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, #1]
\iftikzmark{#2}{\edef\pageA{\PageOfTikzmark{#2}}}{\edef\pageA{-1}}%
\iftikzmark{#3}{\edef\pageB{\PageOfTikzmark{#3}}}{\edef\pageB{-1}}%
\iftikzmarkoncurrentpage{#2}
    \edef\myflag{1}%
\else
    \edef\myflag{0}%
\fi
\iftikzmarkoncurrentpage{#3}
    \edef\myflag{\the\numexpr\myflag+2}%
\fi
\ifcase\myflag
\or
    \node (a) at (pic cs:#2) {};
    \draw ([yshift=0mm,xshift=-1mm]pic cs:#2) to ([xshift=-1mm]a |- current page text area.south);
\or
    \node (a) at (pic cs:#2) {};
    \draw ([xshift=-1mm]a |- current page text area.north) |- ([yshift=1mm,xshift=-1mm]pic cs:#3);
\or
    \draw ([yshift=0mm,xshift=-1mm]pic cs:#2) |- ([yshift=1mm,xshift=-1mm]pic cs:#3);
\fi
\ifnum\value{page}>\pageA
    \ifnum\value{page}<\pageB
        \node (a) at (pic cs:#2) {};
        \draw ([xshift=-1mm]a |- current page text area.north east) to ([xshift=-1mm]a |- current page text area.south east);
    \fi
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{ | l | X | }
    \hline
    \tikzmark{root}\textbf{Member}      & \textbf{Information} \\
    \hline
    \connecttreenodes{root}{node1}
    \hspace{0.3cm}\tikzmark{node1}node1 & 1                    \\
    \hline
    \connecttreenodes{root}{node2}
    \hspace{0.3cm}\tikzmark{node2}node2 & 2                    \\
    \hline
    \connecttreenodes{node2}{node3}
    \hspace{0.6cm}\tikzmark{node3}node3 & 6                    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}


Problems:

Due to the rendering of the tikz stuff, the document generation takes very long.
I have to increase main memory size and other buffer sizes in order to generate the pdf. If my documents are getting larger, I won't be able to increase the memory sizes anymore, it seems that there are maximum limits.

I already tried to externalize the tikz drawings, but it seems not to work with remember picture, overlay options.
I also tried to put the rendering all in one tikzpicture block, but then the lines were not on the original page but on the last page.
Do you have any suggestions how to improve here?

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Maybe you could avoid tikz and draw the tree with something like https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pmboxdraw ?
